# Ember js: In my example why does the logic in the router continue even though the function used in it has not completed?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to ember js and I am trying to understand routing :)

Here is my controller code:

```
App.AppController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

login: App.Login.create({}),

loginUser: function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: contextPath + 'user/register',
        data:{name:this.login.name, email:this.login.email,password:this.login.password,confirmPassword:this.login.confirmPassword,acceptTerms:this.login.acceptTerms},
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success!');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
}
})
```

Here is where I use the function:

```
App.ChooseServiceIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
redirect: function() {
    var isLoggedIn = this.controllerFor('app').loginUser();
    alert(isLoggedIn);
    if(isLoggedIn){
        this.transitionTo('chooseService');
    }
    else {
        this.transitionTo('app');
    }
}
});
```

It seems, the function loginUser gets called, but the alert(isLoggedIn) occurs before the function completes.(Alert(success) occurs after alert(isLoggedIn).

I could use some help to understand what is going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax means Asynchronous Javascript and XML so it is by definition Asynchronous, which means that it will not stop the code until completion and instead run the callback once it is done loading. You can set *async* to false so that it will stop execution until it is done. You have to be careful though for timeouts and similar.

Check out the available options here: **[$.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**